# Lipschitz Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

> > Is this following graph Lipschitz continuous ?

$$ f(x) = 2x, -10<x<0;$$ 
        $$=-3x^2, 0 \leq x \leq 1$$ 
$$=2x-5, 1 < x <10  $$

> > One can Put the following command in Matlab to plot the graph :
>
> x=-10:0.0001:0;
>   y=2*x;
>   plot(x,y,'-')
>   hold all
>   x=0:0.0001:1;
>   y=-3*x.^2;
>   plot(x,y,'-')
>   x=1:0.0001:10;
>   y=2*x-5;
>   plot(x,y,'-')

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is $C^1$ on $[0,1]$, hence Lipschitz continuous on this interval.

$f$ is also Lipschitz continuous on the other two intervals.

Lastly, $f$ is also continuous on $\mathbb  R$. Hence $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $\mathbb R $.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Pardon my ignorance. 
Can you please elaborate how the last line concludes the thing.